# TypeScript React component library documentation for properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have a component library that is structured as a monorepo. Each component is an independent package and the documentation generation is also a separate package.

I am using docz to create my documentation which uses react-docgen-typescript to create the properties documentation. The problem I have is that I cannot get the documentation for the properties and have tried two approaches

1. If I make my component `package.json` point to the TypeScript it does not recognize the source as being TypeScript and raises an exception :(
2. If I make my component `package.json` point to the transpiled version, the propeties are not populated since I don't use PropTypes

How do I go about generating a the properties documentation? Is there are way to extract it from the type declaration files?

Answer (score 0):

You should have `declaration: true` in your tsconfig.json. This way you get

- .js files (contains `PropTypes`)
- .d.ts files (recognized by TypeScript).

Comment: I do have `declaration: true` *.d.ts is created, but as far as I understand, TypeScript will not generate proptypes. Which makes sense since React ships prop types in a separate package from v15.5 onwards